# On SE blogs some author names are linked to broken links

Tags: bug, blog, 404-not-found, blog-overflow

Here are a few blog posts where the author name is broken link:

- Programmers: [Tools are not skills](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/tools-are-not-skills/) — broken link to [Ed Woodcock](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/author/Ed%20Woodcock/)
- Programmers: [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) — broken link to [Andrew Thompson](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/author/Andrew%20Thompson/)
- EL&U: [One Language, Many Voices](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2013/06/one-language-many-voices/) — broken link to [Barrie England](http://english.blogoverflow.com/author/Barrie%20England/)
- Islam: [Introduction](http://islam.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/introduction/)  — broken link to [AlUmmat%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF](http://islam.blogoverflow.com/author/AlUmmat%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF/)

Programmers and EL&U have a number of other blog posts with the author name as a broken link, but only for some of the posts. I've only seen the issue when the author name includes something which renders as into html with a % escape character, e.g. a space, but not every instance of an author name with a space leads to a broken link ([for example](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2013/07/chat-vs-comment/)). Seems like a case of failing to link to user name and instead linking directly to a display name? Or something along those lines.

A few blog sites were checked, and the problem was only seen on Programmers, EL&U and Islam but if whatever engine is powering these blogs is powering any other SE site blogs, then the problem also likely exists elsewhere too.